# Julia: how to concatenate characters of vector together (["a", "b", "c"] -> "abc")

Tags: string, character, concatenation, julia

How to concatenate characters or strings in a vector together in one string so that ["a", "b", "c"] becomes "abc"?

I've tried with vcat, hcat, but nothing seems to work... Thank you

## Answer

`join(["a", "b", "c"])`

Comment: `a = ["a", "b", "c"]; string(a...)`

Comment: why does `join(a)` not work for you though?

Comment: join() works indeed! Dunno what happened

Comment: glad to hear it :). Having said that, voting to close this as a typo. :p

Comment: Add this as an answer and mark it answered.

Comment: I suggest you mark one of the given answers as accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to concatenate a vector of strings:

- `join` function
- `string` function
- `*` concatenate function

as shown by the various comments.

However, the calling signatures for these functions are not identical.  I did not notice this at first, and someone else new to Julia might appreciate the details.

```
julia> j = join(a)
"abc"

julia> s = string(a...)
"abc"

julia> m = *(a...)
"abc"

# When called correctly all three functions return equivalent results.
julia> j == s == m
true
```

**However**, when someone, like myself, is new to Julia, they might not immediately recognize (I didn't) the critical importance of `...` for the `string` and `*` string concatenate functions, in contrast to the `join` function.

For example:

```
julia> s2 = string(a)
"[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"

julia> s == s2
false

# or simply:
julia> join(a) == string(a)
false
```

What is the difference between `s = join(a)` and `s2 = string(a)`?

```
# Note that join(a) produces a string of 3 letters, "abc".
julia> length(s)
3

# string(a) produces a string of punctuation characters with the letters.
julia> length(s2)
15

julia> s[1]
'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

julia> s2[1]
'[': ASCII/Unicode U+005b (category Ps: Punctuation, open)

julia> s[1:3]
"abc"

julia> s2[1:3]
"[\"a"
```

The `*()` concatenation function is also quite different from the `join` function:

```
julia> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"

julia> j = join(a)
"abc"

julia> m = *(a)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching *(::Array{String,1})

julia> m = *(a...)
"abc"
```

Thus the "splat" operator, `...`, which is used to apply a function to a sequence of arguments is crucial to `string` and `*`, but not to `join`.

In fact, the `join` function with the "splat" operator does something you probably don't want:

```
julia> join(a...)
"a"
```

Answer (score 2):

Small addendum:
you can even use `join()` to concatenate a `String` vector with adding a separator:

```
join(["a", "b", "c"], " | ")

"a | b | c"
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = ["a", "b", "c"]; string(a...)`

`join(["a", "b", "c"])`